# How to concatenate all lists (each lists are made my for loop)

Tags: python

I'm crawling webpage by python BeautifulSoup, requests, Pandas library,
trying to collect information of many items in many pages by for loop.
But when I run these code,
I could only get lists separated from each others, so I want to edit this code to concatenated by one list.

- Well, actually my problem is not 'concatenating list' itself.
  I know it already, but the problem is,
  In case of the fuction gives a result that 'list' one by one,
  how can I edit the code to make a result that gives 'one list' that concatenated all together, Or return [[list],[list],[list]] form that I can easily concatenate all together.

Windows, Jupyter Notebook, Python

```
def a(content):
    ptag_title=content.find("p",{"class":"title"})
    ptag_price=content.find("p",{"class":"price-sale"})
    return {"title":ptag_title.text, "price":ptag_price.text}

def get_pd_page(url):
    result = requests.get(url)
    bs_obj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.content,"html.parser")
    pbl=bs_obj.find("div",{"class":"product-box-list"})
    contents = pbl.findAll("div",{"class":"content"})
    pdinfo_list = [get_pdinfo(content ) for content in contents]
    return pdinfo_listn = 10

urls = [None] * n
fix_str = "https://www.abcdef.com"

for page_num in range(0,n):
    page_str = fix_str + str(page_num+1)
    urls[page_num] = page_str
    page_products = get_pd_page(urls[page_num])
    print(page_products)
```

result for each pages are separated lists.

```
[{'title':a, 'price'=b},{'title':c, 'price'=d}] [{'title':d, 'price'=e},{'title':f, 'price'=g]
```

I want to make this whole one list.

```
[{'title':a, 'price'=b},{'title':c, 'price'=d},{'title':d, 'price'=e},{'title':f, 'price'=g]
```

Or, at least, by lists of lists

```
[[{'title':a, 'price'=b},{'title':c, 'price'=d}],[{'title':d, 'price'=e},{'title':f, 'price'=g]]
```

Comment: The OP also asks how to contacentate list of lists, which the duplicate doesn't answer!

Comment: You can use + operator or a list comprehension to concatenate lists @JaguarBlack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `+` operator to concatenate any number of lists

```
In [19]: li1 = [1,2,3]                                                                                                         

In [20]: li2 = [4,5,6]                                                                                                         

In [21]: li1+li2                                                                                                               
Out[21]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Or use a list comprehension to concatenate the sublists inside a list of lists, also called `flattening` a list

```
In [23]: li = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]  

In [30]: flat_list = [item for sublist in li for item in sublist]                                                              

In [31]: flat_list                                                                                                             
Out[31]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

These are simpler examples then what you are trying to achieve, but a similar approach will solve the problem you have at end!

Comment: Great, glad to help @JaguarBlack :) Please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer if it helped you :) Also consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks for the accept @JaguarBlack  :) Have a great day!